# How to transfer data over bluetooth between ESP32 and Android?

Tags: esp32, bluetooth

I have trying to find examples for codes to exchange data over bluetooth between esp32 devkit module and an Android device. I want to use SDP to broadcast a service and then make my Android app connect to esp socket as client. In Linux I have used bluez library to achieve this functionality. But for ESP32 I only found some documentations using btstack library. However I am unable to use this library. I extract the zip to ~/Documents/Arduino/Libraries but it still it says file not found.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment so I am putting an answer here. @Helmer if you can move these answers to comment it will be a great help. Please refer to these examples to connect and exchange data between a Mobile app and ESP32 dev kit over a Bluetooth communication:

[ESP32 Bluetooth Classic with Arduino IDE – Getting Started](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-bluetooth-classic-arduino-ide/)

[ESP32 BLE + Android + Arduino IDE = AWESOME](https://www.instructables.com/id/ESP32-BLE-Android-App-Arduino-IDE-AWESOME/)

[How to Use Bluetooth(BLE) With ESP32](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Use-BluetoothBLE-With-ESP32/)

[How to Use Serial Bluetooth in ESP32](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/using-classic-bluetooth-in-esp32-and-toogle-an-led)

[ESP32 Arduino: Serial communication over Bluetooth Hello World](https://techtutorialsx.com/2018/03/09/esp32-arduino-serial-communication-over-bluetoth-hello-world/)

[ESP32 BLE + Android + Arduino IDE](https://www.hackster.io/botletics/esp32-ble-android-arduino-ide-awesome-81c67d)

Comment: This looks like a good answer to me (upvote)I know that some sites don't like link -only answers, but what are the odds of them all breaking? Welcome aboard, Lucifer :-)

Comment: Thanks, @MawgsaysreinstateMonica. I am trying my best to answer whichever question I can. I am new in this field and also started my carrier as an IoT developer so got to learn things this way by answering/researching as much I can.